# Initialise spinner with data from db

Tags: java, android

I am working on a project in which I am using php mysql to connect android application with database. My requirement is that , there is a spinner in the layout for which I want to initialise values during run time(values come from db).

I have been trying out this code

```
package com.example.festipedia_logo;

//import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.example.festipedia_logo.details1.LoadAllProducts;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class mainpagetry extends Activity {
     Button button1;
     Button button4;
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        String[] city;
        String loc;
        Spinner spinner;
     //String loc;
        private static String url_all_products =new Global().getcon()+"loc.php";
        Button a;

            // JSON Node names
            private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
            private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
            private static final String TAG_NAME = "eventname";
            private static final String TAG_LOCATION = "location";
            private ProgressDialog pDialog;
            //String category,location;
            // Creating JSON Parser object
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        EditText b;int flag=0;
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;
            // products JSONArray
            JSONArray products = null;
        //ListView l;
        //Spinner spinner;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        //getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.fest);
        //getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.fest);
        Drawable d=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.actionbar);
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(d);

        setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();
        spinner = (Spinner)this.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
         /*city = new String[] { "Mumbai", "Chennai",
                    "Dubai"};

         /*adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,city
                  );
*/


    //      spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
//  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mainmenu, container, false);
        //Intent in = getIntent();
        //loc = in.getStringExtra("loc");
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        //TextView t1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.getlocation);
        //t1.setText(loc);

button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating new product in background thread

                /*final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame,new home1() , "Fest Content"); 
                ft.commit();*/
                String s=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MainActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("loc", 0);
                i.putExtra("category", "Technical");
                i.putExtra("location", s);
                // Closing all previous activities
                //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);

                //new CreateNewProduct().execute();
            }
        });
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // creating new product in background thread

        /*final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame,new home1() , "Fest Content"); 
        ft.commit();*/
        String s=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("loc", 0);
        i.putExtra("category", "Cultural");
        i.putExtra("location", s);
        // Closing all previous activities
        //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);

        //new CreateNewProduct().execute();
    }
});
button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // creating new product in background thread

        /*final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame,new home1() , "Fest Content"); 
        ft.commit();*/
        String s=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("loc", 0);
        i.putExtra("category", "Sports");
        i.putExtra("location", s);
        // Closing all previous activities
        //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);

        //new CreateNewProduct().execute();
    }
});
button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // creating new product in background thread
    /*  final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame,new testing() , "Fest Content"); 
        ft.commit();*/
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("loc", 1);
        // Closing all previous activities
        //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
        //new CreateNewProduct().execute();
    }
});
button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // creating new product in background thread
    /*  final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame,new testing() , "Fest Content"); 
        ft.commit();*/
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("loc", 2);
        // Closing all previous activities
        //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
        //new CreateNewProduct().execute();
    }
});


    }
    public void onBackPressed() {
                finish();

            }
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(mainpagetry.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading festivals. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            //Log.d("test",category);
            //Log.d("test1",location);
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        //  Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable

                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String location = c.getString(TAG_LOCATION);
                        //l.setFilterText(id);
                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        map.put(TAG_LOCATION, location);
                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                //t1.setText("We currently do not have any events for this category at the chosen location");
                    //flag=1;
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */

                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                              android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,TAG_LOCATION
                              );
                        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
            });


        }
        }
    }
```

But I am not able to initialise spinner with the values obtained from db.
The error states: `The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(new Runnable(){}, int, String) is undefined`

I have also tried using this in the void run method :

```
public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */

                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter
                            (
                                    mainpagetry.this, productsList,
                                    R.layout.list_item, new String[] 
                                    {
                                        TAG_LOCATION
                                    },
                                        new int[] {  
                                        R.id.name 
                                        });         
                            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
```

Here it states : `The method setAdapter(SpinnerAdapter) in the type Spinner is not applicable for the arguments (ListAdapter)`
Please help!!!

EDIT:

Screenshot of error
[image: error]

Error for array adapter - `The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(mainpagetry, int, String) is undefined`

Comment: Use `mainpagetry.this` instead only `this` as first parameter of ArrayAdapter constructor

Comment: @Jedil Tried that still giving same error..

Comment: You want to use  ArrayAdapter or SimpleAdapter or what

Comment: @Jedil Anything is fine... Tried both the methods, but errors are popping up

Comment: @ganapathy please try the code I posted and post what errors you have with this.

Comment: @ganapathy Please use ArrayAdapter and Not ListAdapter as in your original constructor, just change `this` and it will compile.

Comment: @kiruwka Ya I am using the array adapter but still getting the same error

Comment: @ganapathy which same ? You mentioned two of them. Please post exact compile error, it will save time on discussions

Comment: Error for array adapter - `The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(mainpagetry, int, String) is undefined`

Comment: But why a downvote??
I have mentioned everything that I have tried...

Comment: @ganapathy Your last parameter to your constructor is also not correct. Please see my answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50921/discussion-between-kiruwka-and-ganapathy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should construct your adapter like this :

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
   (mainpagetry.this, 
   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Note : `this` (Runnable) in your original code changed to `this` instance of outer class(you Activity).

Also, remove the last parameter to match one of the `ArrayAdapter` constructors or make it an array or list of Strings, like this :

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
       (mainpagetry.this, 
       android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item
       Arrays.asList("item1", "item2", "item3"));
```

Comment: This is the cause of the problem anyway 100%. He might have other problems, but this should be as stated above. Let's clarify what else he has.

Comment: @kiruwka I am getting the following error : `The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(mainpagetry, int, String) is undefined`

Comment: @ganapathy please copy-paste the code as is: you are missing `this` after `mainpagetry`, see above : `mainpagetry.this`

Comment: See my first comment of question post, doesn't look familiar?

Comment: @Jedil what are you trying to say ? Seems that you had exactly same idea, then why downvoting it ?

Comment: @kiruwka Please see my edit I have posted the pic of the error

Comment: @ganapathy please see update to my answer. You should also remove last parameter to match one of the constructors. Alternatively you can pass a list of strings(or array of strings) as your adapter's content.

Answer (score 0):

There are no `ArrayAdapter` constructors that take a `Runnable` or a generic `T` (in your case, a `String`) as parameters. See the [JavadDoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html).

Instead of a `String`, you probably want to use a `String` *array* or *`List`* instead.

Also, as @kiruwka stated, the first argument must be a `Context`, so you must use `mainpagetry.this` or some other `Context` instead.